# Record Screen While Using App Android

Tags: android, video, webview, streaming, record

I'm trying to find a way to record the screen while on the application.

More specifically, I have a streaming video playing on Webview and I'm trying to add a feature to record the video being played.

Is there anyway to do that? Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome to use the media projection APIs on Android 5.0+. Whether the video itself will wind up being recorded, I cannot say, as there are DRM-style protections on some of that sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you guide me on how I would implement it using MediaProjection?

Comment: The documentation is almost non-existent, and it takes a good 10 pages in [a book](https://commonsware.com/Android) to explain it, which is well beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. I can point you to [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MediaProjection/andcorder) that implements it, though.

Comment: Thanks I will look into that... Is there any other ways to do this?

Comment: Not without a rooted device.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, You are very helpful.  Is it possible if I could contact you privately to ask questions about Android?

Comment: That's off-topic for here. Visit [my site](https://commonsware.com/warescription) for what I can offer.

Comment: Okay. I downloaded the sample project called andcorder. How would I use it? when I started recording it doesn't let me stop, and where does the recording videos get saved to?

Comment: Control is via the `Notification` that is raised. The output is written to `new File(ctxt.getExternalFilesDir(null), "andcorder.mp4");`. If you go into `Android/data/.../files/` (where `...` is your application ID) in external storage, you should see `andcorder.mp4`, sometime after you stop recording.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't seem to find the folder that you mentioned on the Nexus 7 tablet. Can I save it internal on the device?